# Has anyone has success using Hammer.js Pinch Events on 3D models?

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, hammer.js

I'm using Hammer on an augmented reality project and have success moving, rotating, and placing a 3d model (JSON) using Hammer.js.

I'm trying to use the pinch events to scale the object up and down, but I'm having quite a challenge with the behavior of the model.

In the console, it seems the object's scale is correct based on the gestures, but in the app it takes several gestures to get the model to act and then it quickly inverts upside down.

I'm unable to make the model smaller and it just seems the model is unresponsive to my pinch gestures.

```
    scaleSpeed: { default: 1 }
    onPinchIn: function (event) {
        this.scene.emit('objectScaling')
        const scaleDelta = this.initialHammerScale + (event.scale * this.data.scaleSpeed)

    this.modelScaleRig3D.scale.set(
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.x - scaleDelta),
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.y - scaleDelta),
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.z - scaleDelta)
    )
   }

onPinchOut: function (event) {
    const scaleDelta = this.initialHammerScale + (event.scale * this.data.scaleSpeed)
    this.modelScaleRig3D.scale.set(
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.x + scaleDelta),
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.y + scaleDelta),
      (this.modelScaleRigAtScaleStart.z + scaleDelta)
    )
    }

onPinchStart: function (event) {
    this.modelScaleAtScaleStart = this.modelRig.getAttribute('scale')
    this.initialHammerScale = event.scale   
  },
```

Has anyone had success and has tips for me using hammer pinch events for 3d models?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Getting Started documentation](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/)

> By default it adds a set of tap, doubletap, press, horizontal pan and swipe, and the multi-touch pinch and rotate recognizers. **The pinch and rotate recognizers are disabled by default** because they would make the element blocking, but you can enable them by calling:
>
> `hammertime.get('pinch').set({ enable: true });`
>
> `hammertime.get('rotate').set({ enable: true });`